# Ions not attached but included in chemical formula for tartrazine

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, ions

In some diagrams for tartrazine ($\ce{C16H9N4Na3O9S2}$), I see that $\ce{SO3Na}$ is actually represented as $\ce{SO3^-}$ with a floating $\ce{Na^+}$ next to it. How does this work?

[image: tartrazine]

EDIT: Wait, are they just ionicly bonded together?

Comment: That would be a yes to your ionic bond theory ;)

Comment: Don't worry, there were worse ;)